# Android Eclipse Animation Drawable to Bitmap

Tags: android, eclipse, sprite

There is a **animation drawable** which is like a `gif` that can animate a image frame by frame. My question is how can I substitute that `animation drawable image` in my bitmap in `canvas.drawbitmap`? is it possible or is there anyway I can make my bitmap looks like an gif?

Here's my coding in my onDraw method:

```
resizedpaper = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(resizedpaper, Bitwidth,
            Bitheight, true);
canvas.drawBitmap(resizedpaper, (mazeFirstX * totalCellWidth)
            + (cellWidth / 20), (mazeFirstY * totalCellHeight)
            + (cellHeight / 20), ball);
```

Comment: Just thinking.. why not to use [Drawable Animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html) rather then creating a custom view to display sprites?

Comment: how can I substitute it in resizedpaper bitmap?